# jquery draggable + html5 video not working

Tags: jquery-ui, html5-video, draggable, internet-explorer-11

I´m using jquery UI for making divs draggable.

In one div resides a html5 video .
This is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11.

Please see fiddle here (with IE 11).

http://jsfiddle.net/yXqEV/5/

if you delete the draggable:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

the Video is working again.

What can I do to have dragging and Video working in IE11?

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() call in library for Draggable "block" the click event on video element in IE 11, you have to replace the video controls with your customized one, or remove the video control and bind click event to the video element something like :

> $('.videoClip').click(function() {
>            $(this).get(0).paused ? $(this).get(0).play(): $(this).get(0).pause(); });